# Grouping strings from a single long chain of strings using regex in python

Tags: python, regex, string, split

So I need to first group the entire string into blocks based off the new line between paragraphs, then group blocks that have status as Error.
Then I need to use regex to match Actions and if those actions match, then I need to append the string(first line of the block) to a list.
Very new to python and regex any help would be appriciated.

```
"""

Some string that has some meaning.
Doing Action1 
Some error occurred which is logged
Reason for failures.
status: Error

Some other string that has some meaning
Doing Action2 
Some other error occurred which is logged
Reason for failures.
status: Error

Some new string that has some meaning
Doing Action1
Action was done
Reason for Action.
status: Ok

Some brand new string that has some meaning
Doing Action2
Action was done
Reason for Action.
status: Error
"""
The result expected should be something like this when checking for Action1
[Some string that has some meaning.]
when checking for Action2:
[Some other string that has some meaning,
 Some brand new string that has some meaning]
```

Comment: Please show what you have already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to group by blocks of text in this current formatting you should do:

```
text_split = text.split('\n\n')
```

Where the text is what you wrote as the output(?)

This should give you a list of blocks.
If you then want to filter out string blocks that contain `status: Error` in a new list you should:

```
error_block = [x for x in text_split if 'status: Error' in x]
```